# Create an external URL using Yii CHtml::link correctly

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, yii-chtml

I am trying to create an external URL using the CHtml::link function but it always tries to create an internal link rather than an external link..

So rather than linking to google.com, it is linking to www.mysite.com/www.google.com

Any ideas (ps i know I could write this using standard HTML but i'd link to use the Yii engine as much as possible

Comment: How does you code look like? Maybe you have a typo :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example on CHTML link that I used on an image... It linkes the image with google onclick.

```
CHtml::link( CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/images/android.png'),('www.google.com'), array('class'=>" "));
```

Hope it helps! 
Keep on coding! 
Ares.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Text','http://www.example.com', array('class'=>''));?>
```

The HTTP protocol must have at the beginning of the domain.

Comment: You could also start the URL with `//`. This will leave the choice to the browser.